# PCL not finding QHull includes

Tags: c, point-cloud-library

I am using PCL and noticed that when I include `pcl/surface/qhull.h` there is an error while building:

```
 fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libqhull_r/libqhull_r.h': No such file or directory
```

The content of qhull.h is

```
#include <pcl/pcl_config.h>
#ifdef HAVE_QHULL

#if defined __GNUC__
#  pragma GCC system_header 
#endif

extern "C"
{
#include "libqhull_r/libqhull_r.h"
#include "libqhull_r/mem_r.h"
#include "libqhull_r/qset_r.h"
#include "libqhull_r/geom_r.h"
#include "libqhull_r/merge_r.h"
#include "libqhull_r/poly_r.h"
#include "libqhull_r/io_r.h"
#include "libqhull_r/stat_r.h"
}

#endif
```

So I don't get if `HAVE_QHULL` why can't it find the includes?
How can I solve this?

Comment: That depends on how you compile your project, which compiler you use, whether you use CMake or not, how you installed QHull, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I had to reverse Engineer what PCL expects at CMake level from QHull by reading the dedicated CMake finding scripts. The problem is that the building environment I use is not doing this automatically such that I had to set the expected variables by myself.

Comment: It's good to hear that you found the cause of your problem.  You could make your answer more helpful for future readers by explaining *what you found* in your reverse engineering and what directories you needed to add to your compiler's include path.